# Javascript object array. It's keep on over writing the first element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to make an Object with name, id, and amount

```
var sales = {
             Name:"",
             ID:"",
             Amount: []
             };

var emp = new Array();

// Creating 10 arrays of sales objects
for (var a=0; a < 10; a++) {
    emp[a] = Object.create(sales);
}
```

in the amount I need to enter 4 values for e.g ($5435.90, $234.03, $6563.56, $1234.54)
when i do like this

```
var i=0;
for(var x=0; x<10; x++) {
emp[i].Amount[c] = Number(prompt("Enter amount:"));
i++
}
```

When i run that first entire works fine.. but the second entire going back and over writing the first element..

For example if i enter like this
1) 534, 574, 9767, 345
its stores fine in the

```
emp[0].Amount[0] = 534
emp[0].Amount[1] = 574
emp[0].Amount[2] = 9767
emp[0].Amount[3] = 345
```

2) 345, 6574, 545, 1234

```
emp[1].Amount[0] = 345
emp[1].Amount[1] = 6574
emp[1].Amount[2] = 545
emp[1].Amount[3] = 1234
```

at the end it changes the first array to the second one 
emp[0] and emp[1] are same value

please help.. its 3:47AM
and i been working on this since 9PM
i hope u understand what i am trying to say.. :)

Comment: Please post more complete code.

Comment: adding jsfiddle(or any other collaboration site) would make life easier

Comment: One time it's `Amount`, then `salesAmount`, then `saleAmount`... Please be coherent if you want to avoid errors. And `c` doesn't exists, you should use `push` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing var sales to

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
var sales = function () {
    this.Name = ""
    this.ID = "";
    this.Amount = []
}

var a = new sales();
a.Amount.push(1)
var b = new sales();
b.Amount.push(2)

$("#result").append(a.Amount[0])
$("#result").append(b.Amount[0])
</script>
```

Comment: You should add that `emp[a]` now must be `new sales()` instead of `Object.create(sales)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an Amount array inside sales and changing saleAmount after.

This code worked for me:

```
var sales = {
         Name:"",
         ID:"",
         Amount: []
         };

var emp = [];

// Creating 10 arrays of sales objects
for (var a=0; a < 10; a++) {
emp[a] = Object.create(sales);
}


for(var x=0; x<10; x++) {
     for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
         emp[i].Amount[x] = Number(prompt("Enter amount:"));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `i` and `x` confused in inner loop, must be `emp[x].Amount[i]`. 2)It doesn't help, each Amount-array is overwritten with the last values.

Answer (score 0):

[*Object.create*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) creates a new object and sets its `[[Prototype]]` to the provided Object. So when you do:

```
for (var a=0; a < 10; a++) {
    emp[a] = Object.create(sales);
}
```

all of the Objects created have the same `[[Prototype]]`, so they all share the same *Name*, *ID* and *Amount* properties.

To create instances of *Sales*, do:

```
function Sales(name, id, amount) {
  this.Name = name;
  this.ID = id;
  this.Amount = amount;
}

var emp = [];

// Creating 10 arrays of sales objects
for (var a=0; a < 10; a++) {
    emp[a] = new Sales();
}
```

Note that in your code:

```
emp[i].salesAmount[c] = Number(prompt("Enter amount:"));
```

should be:

```
emp[i].Amount[c] = Number(prompt("Enter amount:"));
```

since instances don't have a *salesAmount* property.